# What was kaiju blue?

Tags: plot-explanation, pacific-rim

In the intro to the movie *Pacific Rim*, they mention Kaiju Blue being somewhat of a problem after a kaiju was taken down. I didn't quite understand what it was or why it was a problem. What was it?

Comment: I also found this concept of kind of a fallout from Kaiju blood quite interesting when I heard it and hoped they would elaborate more on this. Yet they completely dropped it from then on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It got elaborated in [wikia](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Kaiju_Blue) pretty well:

> "Kaiju Blue" is the Blood of the monsterous Kaiju creatures. It is
>   also highly toxic to the Earth and Humans. It can instantly poison the
>   land it falls on. Everything gets stained, Peoples skin, their nails,
>   everything. and if it gets into the human system, the suferer will
>   begin to cough up blue vapour. -

Comment: It also appeared to be highly corrosive, only able to be handled following treatment with ammonia.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to *AnkitSharma*'s correct answer to the question of what it actually was I'd just like to add another viewpoint that occurred to me in the wake of the recent *Godzilla*-hype.

Radiation has always been a strong element of the *Godzilla*-franchise, especially *Godzilla*'s nature as a radioactive monster and his meaning as a symbol for the dangers of nuclear weapons and radioactivity in general. So since the obvious influence of *Godzilla* on *Pacific Rim* is undenyable, being *the* Kaiju-movie(s) par excellence, it may very well be that Kaiju Blue and its devastating and toxic effects are also a **reference/hommage to exactly this strong radiation aspect of the *Godzilla*-movies** and other Kaiju-movies they spawned.